# imagemagick installation error - architecture mismatch

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to install ImageMagick via macports but am getting the following error msg:

```
Error: Cannot install imagemagick for the arch(s) 'x86_64' because
Error: its dependency bzip2 is only installed for the arch 'i386'
Error: and the configured universal_archs 'i386 ppc' are not sufficient.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

This looks like the same question that was asked on Superuser, "[Mac ports installation of gcc46 failing due to architecture problems](https://superuser.com/questions/176561/mac-ports-installation-of-gcc46-failing-due-to-architecture-problems/178724#178724)", and on Apple.Stackexchange, "[Mac ports installation of gcc46 failing due to architecture problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258/mac-ports-installation-of-gcc46-failing-due-to-architecture-problems)".

Did you start building these MacPort binaries on MacOS 10.5, then upgrade to 10.6 -- or move to a new machine with 10.6 and copy the MacPorts files from the old machine -- and then build imagemagick under MacOS 10.6?

Does your configuration file `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` differ from `macports.conf.default`? That's a sign that the MacPorts environment was migrated from 10.5 instead of being created new on 10.6.  There should be a line there, reading `universal_archs ppc i386 ppc64 x86_64`.

The **[official MacPorts migration instructions](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)** explain how to essentially update your environment for MacOS X 10.6 and do a complete rebuild. Their instructions:

- Reinstall Xcode and MacPorts
- Update `macports.conf`
- Save a list of installed ports
- Uninstall all ports
- Reinstall just those you still want

The blog post **[Universal Binaries in Macports](http://rcaguilar.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/universal-binaries-in-macports/)** gives slightly different instructions.  Basically it comes down to:

- update the `universal_archs` line in `macports.conf`
- force a complete rebuild with `$ sudo port upgrade --force installed`  -